# Using "discriminated against"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, passive-voice, style

In my sentence, there are some users are discriminated against by some operator. If I want to refer to users' data, I say:

> reveal those discriminated against users' data

Is this correct use of discriminated against? I am using this sentence form for first time. So please excuse my question.

Comment: That's not a complete sentence. It doesn't sound right as it currently stands, but it might if the rest were known. Unlike the existing two answers, a different meaning could be *reveal those discriminated against* ***from*** *users' data*. This actually seems more likely to me based on what you've said. Some unscrupulous operator who sifts through user data and then uses it against key people. But you need to clarify what it is that you mean to express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to say is, "reveal the data of those users who were discriminated against." It would be technically correct to say, "reveal the data of discriminated-against users" -- you can turn the phrase into an adjective by hyphenating it like I did there, but it's very awkward.

That said, I'm not sure what you mean by "discriminated against", "users", and "operator" here. "Discriminated against" is normally used to describe the victims of some sort of prejudice, like "The racist discriminated against black people". Is that what you're talking about? "Discriminate" can also mean to make fine distinctions, like "People with color blindness often cannot discriminate between blue and green." But if you're not referring to prejudice, you may want to use different words.

"Operator" can mean a person who control a piece of equipment, like "the operator of the lathe in the factory". Or it can refer to a mathematical function, like "the conventional arithmetic operators are plus, times, minus, and divided by". There are other less common meanings and perhaps you mean one of them.

Comment: I mean racist context

Answer (score 0):

A long descriptive phrase before a noun can be confusing.

In these cases it is common to move the description after the noun. You can use "of" instead of "'s" and you can use a relative clause.

> Reveal the data of users who have been discriminated against.

This is much clearer